# How can I remove the safe area padding of a BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter

I am using a `BottomNavigationBar` and want to remove the safe area / viewInsets padding given to the bar. I am not referring to the typical answers to similar questions (setting font size to zero or hiding the labels). I am referring to the system padding added to keep the bar above system items like the iPhone X bottom bar, which seems to be the value of `MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom`.

The reason is that in some situations I want to place something *below* the `BottomNavigationBar`, as odd as that sounds. In this case, the additional padding is still supplied and makes the bar have an awkward amount of padding below it before the bottom widget.

Is this even possible or would I need to construct a custom widget instead?

Comment: can yo provide your code or image screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a simple way to do this with `BottomNavigationBar`. There may be a complicated way with different sorts of clipping or custom paints, but ultimately decided it was easiest to create a custom navigation bar using a `Container`. It ended up being even simpler than an actual `BottomNavigationBar` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct:

```
<SafeAreaView edges={['right', 'left', 'top']} >
```

But it really depends on your code.

Comment: This does not appear to be Dart code, but React?

Comment: Damn, my bad, it didn't have the flutter tag when I wrote the answer, and react native has BottomNavigationBar haha 

Answer (score 0):

You can use SafeArea - If the UI you don't care too much =))

```
SafeArea(
  top: false,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('AppBar'),
    ),
    body: const Text("data"),
  ),
);
```

Or you can have it auto-hide

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
    SystemUiMode.manual,
    overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top],
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

However, you can combine the two.

Hope useful to you! xD

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question - this is for `BottomNavigationBar` and not `AppBar`. Also I want to *remove* the safe area padding that is there by default, not add safe area padding.